# Регулярное выражение в JS и определение главной страницы

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

**Задача:** Нужно определить находимся ли мы на главной странице или нет посредством JS. 
**Дано:** url главной страницы всегда начинается с локали /ru/ или /en/.

**В чем проблема:** не могу составить регулярку так, чтобы наше условие **if** срабатывало только когда у нас адрес такой http://www.exemple.com/ru/ или такой http://www.exemple.com/en/, но не, к примеру, такой http://www.exemple.com/ru/category/.

Вот код:

```
var urlpattern = new RegExp("\/(ru|en)\/"); 
if (urlpattern.test(window.location.pathname)) { 

};
```

Как итог:

- Подскажите как правильно составить регулярное выражение?
- Правильно ли я поступаю используя для сравнения пути метод test()?

Comment: регулярка не работает тогда когда у вас на главной нет  `ru|en`?

Comment: На главной всегда нас редиректит на `ru|en`. Поэтому сказать не могу, работает или нет в случае если нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `$` для проверки конца текста:

```
var urlpattern = new RegExp("/(ru|en)/$");
```

Или так:

```
var urlpattern = /\/(ru|en)\/$/;
```

Метод `RegExp#test()` вполне подходит для проверки на совпадение по регулярному выражению.

- `/` - прямой слеш (экранирование этого символа в конструкторе `RegExp` не требуется)
- `(ru|en)` - подстроки `ru` или `en`
- `/`  - прямой слеш (если он необязательный, надо просто добавить кванификатор `?` (= *1 или 0 повторений*): `new RegExp("/(ru|en)/?$")` или `/\/(ru|en)\/?$/`)
- `$` - конец строки.

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/NoPIrE/1).

```js
var urls = ['http://www.exemple.com/ru/',
 'http://www.exemple.com/en/',
 'http://www.exemple.com/ru/category/',
 'http://www.exemple.com/en/',
 'http://www.exemple.com/ru'];
var rx = /\/(ru|en)\/?$/;
for (var url of urls) {
   console.log(url, "=>", rx.test(url) ? "найден": "не найден");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ и разъяснение. Работает.

Comment: Пробуйте эту регулярку на вот эту строку `http://www.exemple.com/ru`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Если последний слеш необязательный, надо просто добавить кванификатор `?` (= *1 или 0 повторений*) - `new RegExp("/(ru|en)/?$")` / `/\/(ru|en)\/?$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да конечно

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Но все ровно не работает если линк такой
`http://www.exemple.com/ru`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan [Работает, и ещё как!](https://regex101.com/r/NoPIrE/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew странно, сейчас еще проверю, если не будет скрин скину.

Comment: Этот вариант ты то же скинул `/\/(ru|en)\/?$/` он вот не рабочий, `/` с начало и с конца не нужен

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew что бы мог найти `/ru`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan: `/\/(ru|en)\/?$/` и используется в [демо](https://regex101.com/r/NoPIrE/2). Вот ещё [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtvdmoqa/) (этот же код добавлен в ответ).

Answer (score 0):

Вот ваша работающая регулярка:

```
var urlpattern = new RegExp("\/(\/|ru|en)\/$");
```

Точнее будет если сделайте так:

```
var urlpattern = new RegExp("(ru|en|ru\/|en\/|\.com\/|\.com)$");
```

И надо проверить `window.location.href` вместо `window.location.pathname`.
Но в место `com` должны поставить окончание вашего домена.

Comment: Интересно кто за правильный ответ минусует?

Comment: Не я. Толко у вас регулярка находит также `///` в конце строки.

Comment: Пробовал ли ты применять указанную регулярку к `http://www.exemple.com/`? @WiktorStribiżew, даже не `//`, а `///`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да если дать регулярке просто тупо текст, а если линк то не найдет, в линке такого просто быть не может. мы не в тексте делаем поиск. а по `url`․

Comment: @Grundy: У меня раскладка не поменялась, я 3 слеша хотел сразу написать. Размик, я понимаю, просто нет смысла добавлять лишний `/` в качестве альтернативы в группе.

Comment: @Grundy подойдет обновленный ответ?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, нет. Посмотри, пожалуйста, что возвращает [window.location.pathname](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-location-pathname), который и проверяется автором вопроса.

Comment: @Grundy Я смотрел на таких линках сейчас скину
`http://www.exemple.com/ru/` , `http://www.exemple.com/en/` , `http://www.exemple.com/ru` , `http://www.exemple.com/en` , `http://www.exemple.com/` , `http://www.exemple.com`. И каждый работает.

Comment: @Grundy  Я про эту регулярку `"(ru|en|ru\/|en\/|\.com\/|\.com)$"`

Comment: Я тоже про нее. `http://www.exemple.com/en/category/status.com`. Но я хотел обратить внимание на то, что проверяется только путь, без схемы и домена.

Comment: @Grundy Правильно, мне кажется он должен проверить вот это `window.location.href` а не `window.location.pathname`? Как думаете?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, зачем? если это его сайт, то особого смысла проверять домен нет

Comment: @Grundy для того что бы вот эта регулярка работало, и если завтра дефолтного редиректа не будет на `ru` или `en` с ного не лазать по кодам и менять его.

Comment: `ru` и `en` не относятся к домену никак

Comment: @Grundy да но человеку нужно узнать это главная страница или нет, сейчас у него происходит редирект на `ru` или `en` кода заходят `example.com` а если завтра этого редиректа не будет?